# Combine two tables based on the first table records

Tags: python, mysql, join

I have two tables like this,

```
  Class  |  Name     | Unit  | Year
 --------+-----------+-------+--------
  10th   |  Language |  2    | 2014
  10th   |  Maths    |  3    | 2014
```

Second table,

```
      Name  | Title | Period | Syllabus
  ----------+-------+--------+-----------------------------
   Language |Unit1  | 8      | Subject1, Subject2, Subject3
   Language |Unit2  | 9      | Subject4, Subject5, Subject6
    Maths   |Unit1  | 7      | Subject1, Subject2, Subject3
    Maths   |Unit2  | 8      | Subject4, Subject5, Subject6
    Maths   |Unit3  | 9      | Subject5, Subject6, Subject7
```

And the result Should be,

```
      Language

      Title | Period | Syllabus
    ----------------------------------
     Unit1  | 8      | Subject1, Subject2, Subject3
     Unit2  | 9      | Subject4, Subject5, Subject6

      Maths

      Title | Period | Syllabus
    ----------------------------------
     Unit1  | 7      | Subject1, Subject2, Subject3
     Unit2  | 8      | Subject4, Subject5, Subject6
     Unit3  | 9      | Subject5, Subject6, Subject7
```

Second table result is base on the first table name..

Can anyone help me in python with mysql? i'm very to python..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--To get language details:
SELECT title, period, syllabus
FROM Second
WHERE Name = 'Language' --replace language with Maths here to get maths subject details

--To get details from table1 and table2
SELECT s.title, s.period, s.syllabus, r.year
FROM Second s INNER JOIN First f
ON f.Name = s.Name
WHERE Name = 'Language' --replace language with Maths here to get maths subject details
```

Comment: Actually its a large database.. So we can't change the subject name like maths and language manually.. That's the problem..

Comment: Didnt got you? What do you mean?

Comment: we need to fetch the result based on the first table subject name.. But it's a large database there are lots of classes from 1 to 10 and lots of subjects. so we can't change the subject name manually.. It'll be better if i get a answer with jquery, or ajax or python with mysql..

Comment: So just get the distinct name `SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM First` and store them in a list with python and then you could iterate over the list and querying DB everytime you need say for language or maths subject or i would suggest you fetch all the result and do grouping in your python code if you need all the data together